# RoR missing attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have model `User` with an attribute `email`. I have to validate inclusion of an email, so I add the line:

```
validates_inclusion_of :email, in: User.select("email")
```

but then I get an error `missing attribute: preferences`

I definitely have the column in the database, I also validate presence and format of an email and everything worked fine till I added that line.

What may cause such an error?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? That the email is the same as an already existing email?

Can you show the full class? Incl. Stacktrace of the error.

In any case: you are using the old validation syntax. And this way the list will be initialized when the class is loaded. You probably want to move this into a lambda or a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It's `User.pluck("email")` not `User.select("email")`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve too.

Is it not possible to validate like that?

```
  validates :email, presence: true
```